# How to make usbmount use /etc/fstab configuration

Tags: linux, automount

I'm using a Debian wheezy stable and I'm trying to automatically mount a specific usb device in a designated directory when it's plugged (not at boot time or with the `mount` command).

I know how to mount my device in the directory I want with `/etc/fstab` and the `mount -a` command with this `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" /media/myFolder  ntfs  auto,exec,rw,user,suid,uid=1000 0 0
```

I also know how to use `usbmount` to mount a device when it is plugged.

My problem is that usbmount mounts the device in a folder `/media/usbX` and not in the directory specified in `fstab`.

I didn't find how to change the configuration of `usbmount` to make it respect the `/etc/fstab`file.

Is it possible and if so how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out MOUNTPOINTS in /etc/usbmount/usbmount.conf.

```
# Mountpoints: These directories are eligible as mointpoints for
# removable storage devices.  A newly plugged in device is mounted on
# the first directory in this list that exists and on which nothing is
# mounted yet.
MOUNTPOINTS="/media/usb0 /media/usb1 /media/usb2 /media/usb3
             /media/usb4 /media/usb5 /media/usb6 /media/usb7"
```

Comment: The problem with the MOUNTPOINTS is that it seems that it makes my directory available for a new mount but my specific USB drive isn't always mounted in the directory I want.

Comment: It appears to be a bug. There is a patch here https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=350633

Comment: That seems to be what i'm looking for. I can't test right now but I'll give a feedback when I can.